# split one python list or dataframe with single column into a pandas dataframe multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a list with 290 items in it (index 0-289) and I'm wondering how to split this long list into a dataframe with 10 columns and 29 rows.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create `numpy.array` and then [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
#python 3
L = list(range(290))
#python 2
#L = range(290)
print (L)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289]
```

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.array(L).reshape(29,10)))
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
1    10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
2    20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
3    30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
4    40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49
5    50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
6    60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
7    70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79
8    80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89
9    90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99
10  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109
11  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119
12  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129
13  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139
14  140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147  148  149
15  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  159
16  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169
17  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179
18  180  181  182  183  184  185  186  187  188  189
19  190  191  192  193  194  195  196  197  198  199
20  200  201  202  203  204  205  206  207  208  209
21  210  211  212  213  214  215  216  217  218  219
22  220  221  222  223  224  225  226  227  228  229
23  230  231  232  233  234  235  236  237  238  239
24  240  241  242  243  244  245  246  247  248  249
25  250  251  252  253  254  255  256  257  258  259
26  260  261  262  263  264  265  266  267  268  269
27  270  271  272  273  274  275  276  277  278  279
28  280  281  282  283  284  285  286  287  288  289
```